# The algebras of compact operators on $\ell_p$ as direct limits of matrix algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces, operator-algebras

Consider $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ as $B(\ell_p^n)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $p\in[1,\infty)$, and include $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ in $M_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ as the upper left corner. Is it true that $\overline{\bigcup_n M_n(\mathbb{C})}=K(\ell_p)$ where $K(\ell_p)$ denotes the compact operators on $\ell_p$?

I know it is true when $p=2$. Also, I know that for $p\in[1,\infty)$, every $L_p$-space has the approximation property so every compact operator is approximable but does this imply the above?

Comment: @TomekKania, it is. I am just hoping that someone can give a conclusive answer for the $p=1$ case. I looked at the paper you referred to but unfortunately I don't really understand it. I guess I'll wait for maybe one more week.

Comment: Yes, I understand that is because the proof in the $p>1$ case uses a property that $\ell_1$ does not have.

Comment: I wanted to add a remark that it is shown in Example 1.10 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.6406v1.pdf that the statement is not true when $p=1$, and in fact there is a rank one operator on $\ell_1$ that is not in the closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** for $p\in (1,\infty)$. The reason is that the canonical basis of $\ell_p$ in this case is shrinking (a basis in a Banach space is *shrinking* if the coordinate functionals form a basis of the dual space; every basis in a reflexive space is shrinking).

Let $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a shrinking basis in a Banach space $E$ and let $(e_n^*)_{n=1}^\infty$ be the associated coordinate functionals. Set $P_n = e_1\otimes e_1^* + \ldots e_n\otimes e_n^*$ ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). Then for a bounded linear operator $T\colon E\to E$ the following are equiverdicial:

1. $T$ is compact,
2. $\|T-TP_n\|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Note that the ranges of $P_n$ can be identified with $\mathscr{B}(\ell_p^n)$, so the conclusion follows as in this case we have $\|T-P_nTP_n\|\to 0$. As for the proof of the above result you may consult Lemma 2.1 [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.01213.pdf).

Comment: Is it false for $p=1$?

Comment: @cyc, it still might be true but for a different reason. Please see this paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02773000 ; it is proved there that $L_1(\mu)$ has the so-called property (A) which seemingly implies what you want. However, I am no expert on this subject.